# A program is run once and a thread is created and running. How to interrupt the thread by using its name

Tags: java, multithreading

My agenda is to get a name and create a thread with that name when the user input is start.
When the user input is stop, I need to get the thread with the input threadName and interrupt it.

Start command

> java -jar sample.jar start abcdthread

stop command

> java -jar sample.jar stop abcdthread

I list all the threads, using a very common code.

```
public static Thread[] getAllThreads(Thread currentThread) {
    ThreadGroup currThreadGroup = currentThread.getThreadGroup();
    while (currThreadGroup.getParent() != null)
        currThreadGroup = currThreadGroup.getParent();
    Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[currThreadGroup.activeCount()];
    currThreadGroup.enumerate(threadArray);
    return threadArray;
}

public static void printAllThreads(Thread currentThread) {
    Thread[] threadArray = getAllThreads(currentThread);
    for (Thread thread : threadArray) {
        log.info("Thread: " + thread.getName());
    }
}

public static Thread getThreadContainsName(Thread currentThread,
        String threadName) {
    Thread[] threadArray = getAllThreads(currentThread);
    for (Thread thread : threadArray) {
        if (thread.getName().contains(threadName)) {
            return thread;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now I want to launch and terminate a thread from some other class.

```
Class A {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    if(args[0].equals"start){
      B b = new B(args[1]);
      b.begin();
    }else{
    B.stop(args[1]);
  }
  }
}

Class B implements Runnable{
  private String name;
  public B(String str){
    this.name = str;
  }

  public void begin(){
    Thread t = new thread(this);
    t.setName(this.name);
    t.start();
  }

  public void run(){
    while(true){
      Thread.sleep(randomnumber);
    }
  }

  public static void stop(String name){
    Thread t = ThreadUtil.getThreadByContainsName(name);
    t.interrupt();      
  }
}
```

So I use the start from a command prompt.
I am able to see the threads, including the newly created thread.

When I run the stop command from another command prompt, it says, there is not such thread.

Comment: You can't stop threads from command line (threads are only visible to the process that started them, and running something from command line creates a new process each time). Usually there is some kind of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) needed to control background process.

Comment: As explained in the comment above, your code can not work due to the fact that you are running 2 processes. 1 way I can think of to achieve this is to create a new MBean to support this functionality and invoke the special stop operation on that bean making to second process communicate with the first thru JMX.